# Instead of using two different phone numbers for a Twilio Queue, could I use one phone for users and the browser client for support reps?

Tags: twilio

I’m building a queue.  I have one phone line, intended for users calling customer support, configured with a Voice URL of `example.com/caller`.  That address returns TwiML that queues the call:

```
post '/caller' do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "Welcome to Support, please hold!"
    r.Enqueue 'Support Queue'
  end
  response.text
end
```

According to the official call queue example I need another phone line for customer support agents to call, that returns TwiML that dequeues a user in the queue.  Is it possible for agents instead dequeue users using the browser client instead?  Why doesn't this code work?

```
get '/'
  capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new account_sid, auth_token
  # the TwiML app friendly-named 'Agent' has a voice URL set to example.com/agent
  capability.allow_client_outgoing 'Agent'
  token = capability.generate
  erb :support, locals: { token: token }
end

post '/agent' do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial do |d|
      d.Queue 'Support Queue'
    end
  end
  response.text
end
```

The actual error is that when I make a call from my browser using `Twilio.Device.connect()` the call hangs up immediately instead of connecting to the user in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think you need to change the value of the [`allow_client_outgoing`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/capability-tokens#allow-outgoing-connections) parameter to a TwiML Application SID, which you can create in your [account portal](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/apps) or via the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications#list-post).  This SID is what lets Twilio know what URL you want us to request when the instance of Client connects to Twilio.

Also, we recently released a new product called [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) which will automatically route queued calls to an available agent, so you not longer have to have an agent dial into the Queue in order to get calls from it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Was hoping you'd answer Devin!  Thanks so much!